# Rails - Mongrel Time out on file upload from phone

Tags: image, upload, timeout, mongrel, rhomobile

I have a mobile app built using Rhomobile. When I launch an image upload from the phone to the rails server I end up with timeout issues on larger pictures (2+ MBs). I get an error in Mongrel on server side (Rails 2.3.8) and a CURL timeout error on the phone side. Is the timeout an issue from the phone or from the mongrel server?

Mongrel error:

```
Wed Oct 19 09:07:05 -0500 2011: Error reading HTTP body: #<RuntimeError: Socket read returned insufficient data: 13515>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_request.rb:107:in `read_socket'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_request.rb:86:in `read_body'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/http_request.rb:55:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:149:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:149:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Error in Rhomobile App:

```
Net| Operation finished with error 28: Timeout was reached
Net|   CURLNetRequest: METHOD = [POST] URL = [http://www.mywebsite.com/updload/upload_image ] BODY = []
```

I use the AsyncHttp.upload_file command.